# Getting the list of all the source files in the directory passed in Zig

Tags: build, zig

I am trying to write a build code in Zig and I want to loop through my project files to get the source files *.c and *.cpp. For that I have copied the following fragment of code from [this](https://zig.news/xq/zig-build-explained-part-2-1850) website:

```
    pub fn addSources(directory: []const u8, b: *std.build.Builder) ArrayListAligned{
    //Searching for source files
    var sources = std.ArrayList([]const u8).init(b.allocator);

    {
        var dir = try std.fs.cwd().openDir(directory, .{ .iterate = true });

        var walker = try dir.walk(b.allocator);
        defer walker.deinit();

        const allowed_exts = [_][]const u8{ ".c", ".cpp" };

        while (try walker.next()) |entry| {
            const ext = std.fs.path.extension(entry.basename);
            const include_file = for (allowed_exts) |e| {
                if (std.mem.eql(u8, ext, e))
                    break true;
            } else false;

            if (include_file) {
                try sources.append(b.dupe(entry.path));
            }
        }
    }
    return sources.items;
}
```

However, I am getting the error `use of undeclared identifier 'ArrayListAligned'`. From what I understand I am supposed to return a slice of `sources`. But, I don't know Zig enough to understand what that means. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am using **Zig 0.9.1** for this.

Comment: Where did you get `ArrayListAligned` from? It seems like your function should return `![]const u8`. But then in 0.11 you'll get an error about `.iterate`, you'd need to use `openIterableDir` instead of `openDir`.

Have you considered [familiarizing](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/) yourself with the language before embarking on this adventure?

Comment: I must admit I haven't spent a whole lot of time reading on the language.

Comment: Note that zig is under active pre-1.0 development, '0.9.1' as 20 months old release is basically ancient by that standard, while the fundamentals of the language of course haven't changed that much a lot of the details have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the error: `use of undeclared identifier 'ArrayListAligned'`. This is because ArrayListAligned is not defined in the scope, you would need to use `std.ArrayListAligned` but this is likely not what you meant to do.

`@compileLog(@TypeOf(sources.items))` shows that it is a `[][]const u8` (slice of constant slice of u8), so the return value should be `[][]const u8`, not `ArrayListAligned`

> From what I understand I am supposed to return a slice of sources

A slice is a type in the zig language representing a many-item pointer and a length. `[]u8` is a slice of u8 values. Since each source is `[]const u8`, a slice of sources would be `[][]const u8` (or `[]const []const u8`)