# expected type '[]const u8', found 'std.fs.OpenError'

Tags: zig

I am calling a the following function from the build script and I keep getting the error: `expected type '[]const u8', found 'std.fs.OpenError'`.

```
    fn addSources(directory: []const u8, b: *std.build.Builder) []const u8 {
    //Searching for source files
    var sources = std.ArrayList([]const u8).init(b.allocator);

    {
        var dir = try std.fs.cwd().openDir(directory, .{ .iterate = true });

        var walker = try dir.walk(b.allocator);
        defer walker.deinit();

        const allowed_exts = [_][]const u8{ ".c", ".cpp" };

        while (try walker.next()) |entry| {
            const ext = std.fs.path.extension(entry.basename);
            const include_file = for (allowed_exts) |e| {
                if (std.mem.eql(u8, ext, e))
                    break true;
            } else false;

            if (include_file) {
                try sources.append(b.dupe(entry.path));
            }
        }
    }
    return sources.items;
}
```

The function call is as follows: `var jetSource = addSources("./src/jet", b);` where `./src/jet` is the path. From what I understand the Zig is unable to open the directory. But, I don't know why, because the error is dumb and is not detailed enough. I just need a way to get the paths of all the files recursively in a folder I pass that end in `*.c` and `*.cpp`.

I read in the source that `/` is invalid in Windows. I replaced the path with `\\src\\jet` and it still doesn't work.

I am using **Zig 0.9.1** on Windows.

Comment: Just like in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77258806/getting-the-list-of-all-the-source-files-in-the-directory-passed-in-zig) the return type should `![]const u8` otherwise the `try` expressions don't make sense

Comment: Why are using 0.9.1?

Answer (score 0):

> `error: expected type '[]const u8', found 'std.fs.OpenError'`

This is a compilation error. Your function uses [`try`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#try), but doesn't return [an error union type](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Errors). Prefix the return type with `!`. And `source.items` is a slice of slices of `u8`, so your function should specify `![][]const u8` as the return type.

Also, you need to use `try` to call your function: `var jetSource = try addSources(...);`.

Comment: As an example, the path returns in `sources.items` is `I:\CPPProjects\JetFramework\matrix2Tests.cpp`. However, it must be `I:\CPPProjects\JetFramework\src\jet\matrix2Tests.cpp`. Is there a mistake some where? That seems to be the source of `FileNotFound` error.